# Inserting data into column of table with multiple databases and overwriting rows

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm still relatively new to PHP and would appreciate any assistance or a point in the right direction with regards to the following query which I am working on.

I have two databases, from which I am getting the count of calls of companies (within a certain date range) from each database and then merging the queries into one table and displaying the information, and the difference between the two counts, as follows:

ID | Name | Date | FirstDB Count | SecondDB Count | Difference |

Now, I am having two main issues. The first is that the second database table do contain the name or id of the companies. The only way of distinguishing the id is in the name of the table. For example, 'Dial_Table_1', the company id is 1, 'Dial_Table_2', the id is 2, etc. There is a company table in the DB that links the id with the name so I am trying to run through the table names, link them to the ids, and then insert this into the main query. Here is my code so far:

Here are my functions:

```
function getCompanyName($conn, $company_id) {
    $sql_companies ="SELECT name AS company, id AS company_id
                FROM company
                WHERE status = 1
                AND id = '$company_id'";

    return $sql_companies;
}

function getFirstDBTables($conn) {
    $tables = [];

    $q = "SELECT DISTINCT job_table 
        FROM test_type";

    $_tables = $conn->query($q);
    while ($table = $_tables->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tables []= $table["job_table"];
    }
    return $tables;
}
function getSecondDBTables($conn_seconddb) {

    $dial_tables = [];
    $r = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'Dial_Table_%'";

    $d_tables = $conn_seconddb->query($r);
    while ($d_table = $d_tables->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dial_tables []= $d_table["Tables_in_dial_reports (Dial_Table_%)"];
    }
    return $dial_tables;
}

function constructFirstQuery($conn, $startDate, $endDate, $company_id) {
    foreach(getFirstDBTables($conn) as $table) {
        $sql []= "SELECT 
            number.company_id AS company_id,
            com.name AS company,
            DATE(call_start_time) AS `date`,
            COUNT(*) AS  `sub_total`,
            '$table' AS `table`
            FROM $table
            LEFT JOIN number ON number.id = $table.number_id
            LEFT JOIN company AS com on com.id=number.company_id 
            WHERE $table.show IS TRUE
            AND call_start_time BETWEEN '$startDate 00:00:00' AND '$endDate 23:59:59'
            AND $table.processing_complete = 1
            GROUP BY `date`, company_id";
        }
    $sql = implode("\n UNION \n", $sql);
    return $sql = "SELECT company, company_id, `date`, SUM(sub_total) AS FirstDB_Count, 0 AS SecondDB_Count FROM ($sql) AS tempTable1 GROUP BY `date`, company_id";
}

function constructSecondQuery($conn_seconddb, $startDate, $endDate, $company_id) {
    foreach(getSeconddbTables($conn_seconddb) as $table) {
        $company_id = str_replace('Dial_Table_', '', $table);
        $sql_dt []= "SELECT 
                $company_id AS company_id,
                DATE(start_time) AS `date`, 
                COUNT(*) AS sub_total 
                FROM $table 
                WHERE $table.published = 1 
                AND start_time BETWEEN '$startDate 00:00:00' AND '$endDate 23:59:59'
                GROUP BY `date`, company_id"; 
        }
    }
    $sql_dt = implode("\n UNION \n", $sql_dt);
    return $sql_cr = "SELECT ' ' AS company, company_id,`date`, 0 AS FirstDB_Count, SUM(sub_total) AS SecondDB_Count FROM ($sql_dt) AS tempTable2 GROUP BY `date`, company_id";
}
```

And here is my main block of code (I have tried a number of different ideas, and have commented them out):

```
<?PHP

$sql = "";
$sql_cr = ""; 
$sql_companies = "";
$name = "";

$sql = constructFirstQuery($conn, $startDate, $endDate, $company_id);
$result_firstdb = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

$sql_dt = constructSecondQuery($conn_seconddb, $startDate, $endDate, $company_id);
$result_dt = $conn_reportingdb->query($sql_dt) or die($conn_seconddb->error);

/***
* This will save companies ID and names to an array
* And will return an array of the companies
*/
// while ($row = $result_companies->fetch_assoc()) {
//     echo $row['company']. ' ';
//  }
$total_results = array();

while ($row = $result_firstdb->fetch_assoc()) {
    $total_results[$row['company_id']] = $row;
  }
while ($row = $result_dt->fetch_assoc()) {

    //$company_id = $row['company_id'];

    // $sql_companies = getCompanyNames($conn, $company_id);
    // $result_companyNames = $conn->query($sql_companies) or die($conn->error);
    // while ($row2 = $result_companies->fetch_assoc()){
    //     $total_results[$row[$company_id]] = $row2['company_id'];
       //}

if(!isset($total_results[$row['company_id']])) {
    $total_results[$row['company_id']] = $row;

    $company_id = $row['company_id'];
    $sql_companies = getCompanies($conn, $company_id);
    $result_companyNames = $conn->query($sql_companies) or die($conn->error);
    while ($row2 = $result_companyNames->fetch_assoc()){
        $total_results[$row[$company_id]] = $row2['company'];
        //$company_id = $row2['company'];

       //if(!isset($total_results[$row['company']])){
           // $total_results[$row[$company_id]] = $row2['company'];
      //} else {
           //$total_results[$row['company_id']['company']] = $row2['company'];
        //}
    }
} else {
    $total_results[$row['company_id']]['SecondDB_Count'] = $row['SecondDB_Count'];    //**Merging the databases 
  }
}

//array_push($company_data, $total_results);
//print_r($company_data);

//print_r($company_data[$row['company_id']]);
// if(!isset($company_data[$row['company_id']])) {
//       $company_data[$row['company_id']] = $row;
//       //print_r($row);

// } else {
//       $company_data[$row['company_id']]['Spearline_total'] = $row['Spearline_total'];    //**Merge 
//     }


// while ($row = $result_cr->fetch_assoc()) {
//     if(!isset($company_data[$row['company_id']])) {
//       $company_data[$row['company_id']] = $row;
//     } else {
//       $company_data[$row['company_id']]['Reporting_total'] = $row['Reporting_total'];    //**Merge 
//     }
//   }

// }
// }

if ($total_results) {
    echo"<TABLE><TR><TH>Company</TH>
    <TH>Company ID</TH>
    <TH>Date</TH>
    <TH>Firstdb Total</TH>
    <TH>Seconddb Total</TH>
    <TH>Difference</TH></TR>";

    foreach($total_results as $row) {
        $firstdb_total = $row['FirstDB_total'];
        $seconddb_total = $row['SecondDB_total'];
        $difference = ($firstdb_total - $seconddb_total);

        echo"<TR><TD>". $row["company"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row["company_id"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row["date"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row["FirstDB_total"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row["SecondDB_total"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $difference . "</TD></TR>";

      }
      echo"</TABLE>";
    }
```

So the first main issue, is the matching of the names with ids in each database. In Database 1, there is no call count for some of the companies in database 2 so the table at the moment is giving me names of companies which are in DB1, but if they are only included in DB2, then the name is not being returned to the table. If anyone happens to know how I can solve this issue, I would very much appreciate it.

The second issue is that the in the returned table, the dates are overwriting one another. So for each company, instead of getting a call count for each date specified, the rows are being overwritten each time it loops and I am only getting one row counts for each company, no matter how many days are specified.

Help on either question would be really appreciated. As I mentioned, I am still learning this and would love some help. Thanks